# Custom Authorize for both action and api calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, asp.net-web-api

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097356/custom-authorize-attribute-can-i-store-a-value-for-later) and have successfully setup my custom authorize attribute.

But now I have hit another wall regarding api calls. I need these calls to also be authorized in the same fashion as the action calls. I understand that there is a difference between System.Web.Http and System.Web.Mvc Authorize attributes. So I have created a separate Api specific attribute that basically does the same thing. However, I am having trouble setting the User - principal and identity like i do in the original attribute.

My attributes simply check for some values in a cookie to authorize the request, once the attribute has read the cookie I was storing the decrypted cookie information within a custom principal/identity setup. In my Api call, when I go to retrieve this information from the identity my cast fails and i receive a null value.

This is how I store the information

Api

```
HttpContext.Current.User = new MyPrinciple(new MyIdentity(decCookie.Name, decCookie.UserData));
```

Action

```
filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.User = new MyPrinciple(new MyIdentity(decCookie.Name, decCookie.UserData));
```

How I retrieve the desired information I assumed would be the same

```
(User.principal.Identity as MyIdentity).MyData;
```

**Questions**

1. Do I really need to have 2 separate attributes
2. For the Api attribute how can I easily store the information for later use within the controller. Or basically can I not actually get/set the Identity this way for these calls?

**EDIT #1**

I found how to properly access my cookie value from my ApiController, I was simply missing a reference to System.Web >_<. So question #2 has been solved! but #1 still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only inherit in one class from in c#, and each authorizeattribute lives in its own namespace, so you can't do it in a single class.

You could hold it in a common namespace and then call a common class to do the lifting.

Possible solution (untested)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace Common.Attributes
{
public class CustomAuthorize : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated || (HttpContext.Current.User as User) != null)
            return;

        filterContext.HttpContext.User = Authorize.ExtractIdentity(filterContext.HttpContext);
    }
}

public class CustomHttpAuthorize : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated || (HttpContext.Current.User as User) != null)
            return;

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = Authorize.ExtractIdentity(filterContext.HttpContext);
        }
    }  
}

public static class Authorize
{
    public static IIdentity ExtractIdentity(HttpContext context)
    {
        // do your magic here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I see you have set System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal... how does this differ from HttpContext.Current.User?

Comment: I hadn't looked into it tbh, I found that the User object of the api controller was different from the httpcontext.user, so I pushed into the thread principal instead and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 3):

Web API and MVC have nothing in common (technically) - even when they look the same. You need two separate attributes.